# How to make a post request that includes open files?

Tags: python, http, request

Мy query produces the following error

{"ExportedDataFile":["The ExportedDataFile field is required."]}

```py
import requests

files = {'file': open('33332815-2019-04-191419.xml', 'rb')}
payload = {'ExportedDataFile': files, 'Token': 'test'}
r = requests.post("http://????", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Why are you passing in the `files` dictionary as the `ExportedDataFile` key in the `data` mapping? You need to pass in that dictionary as the `files` argument, possibly with the key in that dictionary set to `ExportedDataFile`, so `files = {'ExportedDataFile': open(...)}`, and `payload = {'Token': 'test'}`, then `requests.post(url, data=payload, files=files)`. See the duplicate.

Comment: You passed an open file object in `{'file': ...}`. Files should be passed via `files` argument to `requests.post` presuming that the server on the other end is expecting some multipart MIME document: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request

Answer (score -1):

As @Martijn Pieters points out, you *can* post files, like so:

```py
import requests

files = {'ExportedDataFile': open('33332815-2019-04-191419.xml', 'rb')}
payload = {'Token': 'test'}
r = requests.post("http://????", files=files, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Yes, you **can** post a file object, but not in the way the OP is using it.

Comment: See http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: I dont know... I am makethe first post request

Comment: Blimey, I did not know that. Thanks.